# php - Use session's variable on external page

Tags: php, laravel, session

I need to check sessions variable on external host, e.g.
**Source Site (using Laravel):**

```
session([
    'myVar' => 'valueOfThisVar'
]);
```

**Destination Site:**
I'm dumping `$_SESSION` but I cannot see this variable.
I have tried with cookie too:

```
setcookie('myVar', 'valueOfThisVar', time()+3600);
```

and dumped `$_COOKIE` but it's same effect - I cannot access this variable.
Am I doing sth wrong?

Comment: The main point of a session is it is held on the server and only the server and not in any way sharable

Comment: How can you think that one file on one host can access session on another file on another host?! what about security and privacy?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is there anyway to store it in e.g. Session Storage in browser?

Comment: Probably, but you should let us all know which website is doing this so we can all avoid it like the plague as a security mightmare

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need to store value for verification, nothing important and sensitive, simply_key => simply_value, that's all.